# Node/Express - use API JSON response to (server-side) render the app

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, express-handlebars

Preamble: I'm new to web dev so maybe this might be a very basic question for you vets.

I'm using MVC architecture pattern for this basic app. I've models (MongoDB), views (Express Handlebars), and controllers (functions that take in req, res, next and returns promises (.then > JSON is returned, .catch > error is returned). I'll be routing the paths reqs to their corresponding api endpoints in the controllers.

This makes sense (right?) when I'm purely working on API calls where JSON is the res. However, I also want to call these api endpoints > get their res.json > and use that to render my HTML using Handlebars. What is the best way to accomplish this? I can create same controllers and instead of resp being JSON, I can do render ("html view", res.json). But that seems like I'm repeating same code again just to change what to do with the response (return JSON or Render the JSON).

Hope I'm making sense, if not, do let me know. Please advise.

p.s. try to ELI5 things for me. (:

Edit:

```
//Model Example
const Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;

const testSchema = new Schema({
    testText: { type: String, required: true },
});

const Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

module.exports = Test;


//Controller Example
const model = require('../models');

module.exports = {
    getAll: function(req, res, next) {
        model.Test.find(req.query)
            .then((testItems) => {
                !testItems.length
                    ? res.status(404).json({ message: 'No Test Item Found' })
                    : res.status(200).json(testItems);
            })
            .catch((err) => next(err));
    },
};

//Route Example
const router = require('express').Router(),
    controller = require('../controllers');

router.get('/', controller.getAll);

module.exports = router;
```

I want the endpoints to return JSON and somehow manage whether to render (if the req comes from a browser) or stay with JSON (if called from Postman or an API web URL for example) without repeating the code. I'm trying to not create two endpoitns with 99% of the code being the same, the only difference being .then > res.status(200).json(testItems); vs .then > res.status(200).render('testPage', { testItems}).

Comment: `render('view', {})` seems to me quite logical if you want specific data in a specific view.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO... At first, the question you're asking is too broad. You should share the part of code representing your problem (the controller file for exemple - if not your question will be closed)... [welcome link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) After yes, you can create two routes to go on the same controller action... and  check the path for exemple... if it's ending by `.json` you call the `res.json(...)`

Comment: @MoadEnnagi, I want to somehow call the same endpoint that returns JSOn and be able to show just the JSON (in postman for example) or view that JSON rendered on the app (using express handlebars). I'm struggling with doing these 2-for-1 sorta thing without needing to write two controllers, one that res.json and other that render("view",{}) for the same request.

Comment: @PimentoWeb added a test code. What do you mean by the last thing you mentioned? can you please show an example code or something so I can understand it better? This sounds interesting.

Comment: Hi, just to be clear you want you endpoints to return json if its from postman and html page if its from brower ?

Comment: Hi, I want the endpoints to return JSON and somehow manage whether to render (if the req comes from a browser) or stay with JSON (if called from Postman for example) without repeating the code. I'm trying to not create two endpoitns with 99% of the code being the same and only thing that's different is .then > res.status(200).json(testItems); vs .then > res.status(200).render('testPage', { testItems}).

Comment: if you just want to test your apis in postman well actually, if you see `postman` sends an extra header with all its request which is `Postman-Token` then in your server you can check for this header and know if header send json else send html page

Comment: I believe you can only have one response. You can't respond with json only, and respond with other stuff unless you put some kind of condition.

Comment: @warl0ck I'm not entirely sure what you mean (I haven't used Postman enough yet). Let's say I want to go on the app and type in path for JSON response (www.testexample.com/api/getdata) and see JSON output. On the other hand, I want to go to a page where there's a HTML table which gets populated by output of this endpoint (www.testexample.com/showdata) and see the JSON output rendered in HTML table.

Comment: @MoadEnnagi is there a way to call the API endpoint somehow > grab the api endpoints JSON response > and return it's response as render("view", {res})?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi yes correct you will have one small if else, and you can send different types of responses, and @007  well any request you make with postman you will know from the headers that is postman request  and as for second approach you can actually send a query param with all request for json like `?resp=json`

Comment: @warl0ck, how would you change the above example to accommodate the if/else approach? If possible, I would like to go with that approach.

Comment: @007 I have posted both the method for reference, check if those helps

Comment: There are so many rest clients available. You can't got on a if else ladder for them. You should check user agent field in the headers. You can use regex to check if it's from some common browser or not. Then you can use an if else statement to decide what response to send.

Comment: @DEVCNN, yes true thats why there is method 2 also where in your query params you can specify if you want json or html

Comment: I guess the OP wants it to work for the same request.

Comment: @007 the `method2` is the if else approach i was talking about based on query parameter

Answer (score 0):

For postman you could check the existence of `postman-token` in `req.headers`, then you could render accordingly, something like this:

```
req.headers['postman-token'] ? res.json({ /* json */ }) : render('view', {/ * json */});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with `checking postman token` then you can use similar to `method1`.

if you want to check with query params in this case you can get `json` response or html even from browser for future use also and is not dependent on postman then use similar to `method2` of the following example.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const port = 5000



app.get('/method1', (req, res) => {
  const isJSONResp = req.headers['postman-token']
  const resp = { status: "hello" }
  if (isJSONResp) {
    res.json(resp)
  } else {
    res.render('some.html', resp)
  }
})

app.get('/method2', (req, res) => {
  const params = req.params
  const resp = { status: "hello" }
  if (params.resp === 'json') {
    res.json(resp)
  } else {
    res.render('some.html', resp)
  }
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```